# Calculator bugfixes

Tags: string, screen

I am trying to make Calculator project, by the calculator screen should only 9 digits but in my project more than 9 digits, how can I solve the problem

is expected 9 digits

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.